# How can I wait for button click to make interaction contents with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to wait user's click to make interact contents.
And code below is example with vanilla js.
But with Vue.js, I can't add eventlistener to specific dom element dynamically.
Then, how can I make this with Vue.js?

```js
async mainTask(){
  //something...
  showText.innerText += "please input value and then click ok button.\n";
  const input = await waitInput();
  //...
}

async function waitInput() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        okButton.addEventListener("click",() => {
            const text = someinput.value;
            resolve();
        }, { once:true });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get value from input after user clicking a button. 
in your Vue

```
<template>
 <input v-modle="valueYouWant" />
 <button @click="getValueAndDoSth">
</template>
<script>
// ... common vue script header
 getValueandDoSth(){
  // return this.valueYouWant
}
</script>
```

// Edit Based on your comment
If you want to run some function as soon as page load, you can

- run a function in `mounted` function of Vue component
- once user click the button, get value, and run left code you want to run

I'm not sure 'you want to run a function and wait for user click button and then run left', if user does not click on button, your function stops anyway.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I need await input in the mainTask.  And I can't expect when the mainTask require input before running it.  mainTask is a kind of interpriter.  So it await input at the middle of recursive function calling.

Comment: @invalid updated the answer based or your comment. so you run half of your `mainTask` function and run left part or your `mainTask` in `getValueandDoSth ` function (the click handler)